# not able to setup api testing codeception for yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, codeception

I am working on project built in yii2 and the front end is angular 12 and i am trying to  integrate api testing in my project (locally), i am following the documentation but not able to integrate it properly.

i setup my Api.suite.yml as

```
actor: ApiTester
suite_namespace: \Api
modules:
    # enable helpers as array
    enabled:
        - REST:
            url: http://localhost:4454/meteorwms/backend/web/index.php
            depends: Yii2
```

an i have created a new test with the name of CreateUserCest

```
<?php


namespace Api;

use \ApiTester;

class CreateUserCest
{
    public function _before(ApiTester $I)
    {
    }

    // tests
    public function tryToTest(ApiTester $I)
    {
    }

    public function createUserViaAPI(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $I->amHttpAuthenticated('admin', '123');
        $I->haveHttpHeader('accept', 'application/json');
        $I->haveHttpHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
        $I->sendGet('?r=configuration/user&expand=roles.permissions,companies,warehouses,adjustmentTypes,defaultCompany,defaultWarehouse&per-page=10&page=1');
        $I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
        $I->seeResponseIsJson();
        
    }
}
```

the url is in this pattern

http://localhost:4454/meteorwms/backend/web/index.php?r=configuration/user&expand=roles.permissions,companies,warehouses,adjustmentTypes,defaultCompany,defaultWarehouse&per-page=10&page=1,

whenever i run the test case it returns

Yii-log: [yii\web\HttpException:404] 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException: Unable to resolve the request "configuration/user". in C:\laragon\www\meteorwms\backend\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php:561
Stack trace:
#0 C:\laragon\www\meteorwms\backend\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(103): yii\base\Module->runAction('configuration/u...', Array)
#1 C:\laragon\www\meteorwms\backend\vendor\codeception\module-yii2\src\Codeception\Lib\Connector\Yii2.php(371): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#2 C:\laragon\www\meteorwms\backend\vendor\symfony\browser-kit\AbstractBrowser.php(385): Codeception\Lib\Connector\Yii2->doRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Request))
#3 C:\laragon\www\meteorwms\backend\vendor\codeception\lib-innerbrowser\src\Codeception\Lib\InnerBrowser.php(243): Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\AbstractBrowser->request('GET', 'http://localhos...', Array, Array, Array, NULL, true)

any guidance in this is appreciated

in the last of error it returnns

Html: C:\laragon\www\meteorwms\backend\tests/_output\Api.CreateUserCest.createUserViaAPI.fail.html
Response: C:\laragon\www\meteorwms\backend\tests/_output\Api.CreateUserCest.createUserViaAPI.fail.html
Body:

```
Not Found: Page not found.
```

it is not catching the url through it , i have tried hitting the url with postman and it works fine , but i am not able to hit the url in the test case, am i missing something or is there any other requirement that need to be fulfilled ??

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Issue , Needed to install a package for PhpBrowser , using the command

```
composer require codeception/module-phpbrowser --dev  ,
```

then run the build command

then set the Api.suite.yml as

```
actor: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Yii2:
            configFile: 'codeception/config/api.php'
        - REST:
            depends: PhpBrowser  # Use PhpBrowser as backend
            url: http://localhost:4454/meteorwms/backend/web/index.php
```

and then we can test